# Display a PDF in Salesforce from Blob data

Tags: rest-api, pdf, files, document, blob

For our project, we need to get a PDF via API from an external private filestore, and display it within a Lightning Component. With the blob that is returned, if I set that to the src of an iFrame, it works in some browsers, but not Chrome, due to CSP issues. Same problem if I try a base64 approach. Also, unfortunately srcdoc, embed, and object tags are not supported in Salesforce.

EDIT: I should also add that I tried PDF.js, but couldn't get it to work due to LockerService.

What would be the best approach to getting this file to display?

Is there a way to manually edit the CSP header for things like object-src to allow Blob? Does Salesforce have a built in way to display blob data? Is there an easy way with Apex that I could turn the PDF into an image the same way Salesforce generates previews for content documents?

Comment: Are you building a Lightning component, a Visualforce page ... ?

Comment: Ah sorry, a Lightning component. I'll update original question

Comment: Are you storing this file in Salesforce or this is temporary and you only want to display it?

Comment: @JayantDas Temporary and just want to display it. We're getting the file from an external private filestore.

Comment: Did you find the solution? if so please share your ideas